# Can I uninstall a previous release and then reinstall a newer release using Wubi?

Tags: 12.04, 10.10, wubi

I have Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick Meerkat on my dual-boot laptop right now. However, I want to use the 12.04 LTS release instead. Since I used Wubi, is it possible to uninstall Ubuntu 10.10 from Windows and the install 12.04 from Windows again?

That is assuming nothing goes wrong with Windows when I uninstall 10.10!

Comment: Yes! Not only possible, it is advisable, as Ubuntu 10.10 is no longer supported.

Comment: Do you simply want to install 12.04 from scratch or do you actually want to retain some of your data and settings from within the Ubuntu partition?

Comment: Thanks, I will go ahead with it then. I don't need to retain any data as I haven't used the OS for more than a year.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can just remove Ubuntu from the Add/Remove Programs or Programs and Features control panel, and then install the newer version.

However, if you want to preserve your data and settings, you will need to back up your home directory from within Ubuntu. You can do this by booting into Ubuntu and copying things over to your Windows drive or a USB storage device.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see why it wouldn't be possible, even with Wubi.  You'd simply uninstall the existing installation and install the new one as if from scratch.